# Get both date and time in milliseconds

Tags: c, linux, datetime

I would like to create a function that will fill a struct with the current date and time, such as:

```
typedef struct DateAndTime
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    int msec;
}DateAndTime;
```

I know I can use `localtime()` from `time.h`, but the problem is that it gives me only time in seconds, and I want to get it also in milliseconds resolution. I know I might be able to use also `gettimeofday()` for this, but how can i combine those to get the above struct filled? Or maybe other function that gives milliseconds resolution?

How can i achieve this?

Note: My system is linux based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `gettimeofday()` to obtain the seconds and micro seconds, and then use the seconds to call `localtime()`. You then can fill your structure as you wish.

Line this

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct DateAndTime {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    int msec;
} DateAndTime;

int
main(void)
{
    DateAndTime date_and_time;
    struct timeval tv;
    struct tm *tm;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);

    // Add 1900 to get the right year value
    // read the manual page for localtime()
    date_and_time.year = tm->tm_year + 1900;
    // Months are 0 based in struct tm
    date_and_time.month = tm->tm_mon + 1;
    date_and_time.day = tm->tm_mday;
    date_and_time.hour = tm->tm_hour;
    date_and_time.minutes = tm->tm_min;
    date_and_time.seconds = tm->tm_sec;
    date_and_time.msec = (int) (tv.tv_usec / 1000);

    fprintf(stdout, "%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d %02d-%02d-%04d\n",
        date_and_time.hour,
        date_and_time.minutes,
        date_and_time.seconds,
        date_and_time.msec,
        date_and_time.day,
        date_and_time.month,
        date_and_time.year
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simple as it can be. Thank you for this solution and code!

Comment: Use `.%03d` else 1 millisecond will print out as `.1`.

Comment: Pedantic:  `gettimeofday()` is _usually_ not found on systems with 16-bit `int` and `.tv_usec` is of type `suseconds_t` (signed integer type capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, 1000000].)  IAC, suggest casting to `int` _after_ the division.  `date_and_time.msec = (int) (tv.tv_usec / 1000;)` to cope with 16-bit `int`.  UV anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can feed `localtime` with the `time_t` object returned as a part of`struct timeval` by the `gettimeofday`:

```
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);

struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```